# Merging two data frame lists based on comparing two column values according to one-to-one match rule

Tags: r, list, generics, merge, dataframe

I have two following lists (actual list will be much bigger) :

```
 > ratList
     ratGene      ratReplicate    ratAlignment  ratRNAtype
10    Sdhb   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        reg
11    Fasn   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        reg
12   Dok10   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        rev
13   Hspa5   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        reg
14   Cmpk1   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            3        reg
```

and

```
> humanList
   humanGene                            humanReplicate humanAlignment humanRNAtype
61    DOCK10 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              6          reg
62     NUDT5 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              5          dup
63      GRM8 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              5          rev
64      PHC3 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              7          reg
65      EI24 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt             13          rev
```

Now I want to merge these two lists and make data frame/list `df` of the form

```
humanGene humanAlignment humanRNAtype ratGene ratAlignment ratRNAtype
DOCK10        6            reg         Dok10      2          reg
```

the merging process will be done by help of another text file document geneData.txt of the form :

```
AAED1,Aaed1
AAGAB,Aagab
AAK1,Aak1
AAMDC,Aamdc
AAMP,Aamp
AANAT,Aanat
AAR2,AAR2
```

Here in each line first word corresponds to human gene and the second word corresponds to rat gene (example: AAED1 is human gene, and the corresponding rat gene is Aaed1). I need to merge ratList and humanList in a way so in each row of merged list, I have the corresponding rat and human gene as suggested by the text file. In humanList, if there exists row for a gene that does not exist in ratList, I will simply ignore that gene in making the merged list. And same goes for the genes in ratList that does not exist in humanList.

Could anyone help me do this? I am new to R and data processing is still a mystery for me in R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they lists? or are they data frames? Because they look like data frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

Assuming that the `geneData.txt` can be read into a two column data.frame with `first column`  for `human genes` and second for `rat genes`

```
geneData <- structure(list(human = c("DOCK10", "NUDT5", "SDHB1", "AAED1", 
"AAGAB"), rat = c("Dok10", "Nud5", "Sdhb", "Aaed1", "Aagab")), .Names = c("human", 
"rat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))



  res <-  merge(merge(geneData, humanlist, by.x="human", by.y="humanGene"), ratlist, by.x="rat", by.y="ratGene")

res[,c(2,4,5,1,7,8)]
 #    human humanAlignment humanRNAtype   rat ratAlignment ratRNAtype
 # 1 DOCK10              6          reg Dok10            2        rev
```

In the `example` for geneData:

- `NUDT5` is found in `humanlist`, but `Nud5` not in ratlist
- `Sdhb` is found in `ratlist`, but `SDHB1` not in humanlist
- Some gene names are not found in both the lists
- Here, only `Dok10` and `DOCK10` are found in both the lists

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are data frames and not lists

```
ratList$humanGene <- toupper(ratList$ratGene)
New.df <- merge(ratList,humanList,by="humanGene")
```

There aren't any genes that are the same in that set of data though so this gives New.df as an empty data frame.
Look up `?merge` for additional options.

If they are lists of 1 data frame each

```
ratList[[1]]$humanGene <- toupper(ratList[[1]]$ratGene)
New.df <- merge(ratList[[1]],humanList[[1]],by="humanGene")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two big `data.frame`s to merge, it is preferable to use the `inner_join()` function from `dplyr` package, which is much faster than `merge()`.

First the data:

```
ratList <- read.table(text="
     ratGene      ratReplicate    ratAlignment  ratRNAtype
10    Sdhb   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        reg
11    Fasn   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        reg
12   Dok10   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        rev
13   Hspa5   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            2        reg
14   Cmpk1   Thymus_M_GSM1328752            3        reg
", stringsAsFactors=F)

humanList <- read.table(text="
   humanGene                            humanReplicate humanAlignment humanRNAtype
61    DOCK10 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              6          reg
62     NUDT5 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              5          dup
63      GRM8 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              5          rev
64      PHC3 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt              7          reg
65      EI24 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L004_R1_report.txt             13          rev

", stringsAsFactors=F)

# using the geneData akrun provided
geneData <- structure(list(
  human = c("DOCK10", "NUDT5", "SDHB1", "AAED1", "AAGAB"), 
  rat = c("Dok10", "Nud5", "Sdhb", "Aaed1", "Aagab")), 
  .Names = c("humanGene", "ratGene"), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

In practice, you can read in the `geneData` using,

```
geneData <- read.csv("geneData.csv", header=F)
names(geneData) <- ("humanGene", "ratGene")
```

Here are some quick benchmarks:

#### merge

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  merge(
    merge(geneData, humanList, by="humanGene"),
    ratList, by="ratGene"
  ), unit="us"
)
```

Output:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                                              expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
 merge(merge(geneData, humanList, by = "humanGene"), ratList,      by = "ratGene") 1517.795 1565.213 1584.099 1645.475 6441.493
 neval
   100
```

#### `dplyr`

```
microbenchmark(
  inner_join(
    inner_join(humanList, geneData, by="humanGene"),
    ratList, by="ratGene"
  )
)
```

Output:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                                                        expr     min      lq   median     uq
 inner_join(inner_join(humanList, geneData, by = "humanGene"),      ratList, by = "ratGene") 251.666 256.388 258.4405 261.93
     max neval
 488.142   100
```

You can see that `dplyr:::inner_join()` is about 6x~7x faster than `merge()`, which is something to consider if you have to join big tables repeatedly.